# ArcGIS Raster Shows No Compression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, compression

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 to add raster layers to a geodatabase. When I create a new 32-bit floating-point raster layer, I specify that it should use "Packbits".

After the layer is created, I check Layer -> Properties and find `Compression = NONE`. I expect it should say Packbits.

The same is true for LZW (`Compression = None`)

Meanwhile, RLE shows `Compression = LZ77`

Why am I getting these unexpected behaviours?

No errors/warnings appeared during layer creation.

[image: Geodatabase Properties]

[image: Creating a new raster layer]

[image: Setting the compression method]

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the image format (the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/raster-compression.htm) states that `PackBits` *Applies to TIFF only*)

Comment: @Vince: I noticed that shortly after asking the question. As far as I can tell, the format in question is the ArcGIS FGDB raster format. I'm not sure why they offer TIFF options in their dialogue.

Comment: "Add to geodatabase" has so many potential meanings, it fails to have any. A catalog or raster dataset would actually use a filesystem GeoTIFF.

Comment: @Vince: I've added pictures. Does this help?